# $M \otimes_R \kappa(m) = 0$ implies that $M = 0$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and $M$ a finitely generated $R$-module. For a maximal ideal $m$ of $R$, we let $R_m$ denote the corresponding local ring and $\kappa_m$ denote its residue field (this is obtained by taking the quotient $R_m/\mathfrak{m}$ of $R_m$ by its maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$).

Suppose I construct a map $$\varphi_m:R \rightarrow \kappa_m, r \mapsto \frac{r}{1}\mathfrak{m},$$
which is a ring homomorphism, and then I take the tensor product $M \otimes_R -$ to obtain the map $$M \otimes_R \varphi_m: M \otimes _R R \rightarrow M \otimes_R \kappa_m.$$

Now I'm not sure how is this map defined, I'm guessing it should send an element $(n,r)$ to $n(\frac{r}{1}\mathfrak{m})$. But at the same time, we also know that $M \otimes_R R \cong M$ which means now I have no idea what should $n \in M$ be mapped to.

I'm not sure this is the correct approach because ultimately I'm trying to show that

> Assume that $M \otimes _R \kappa(m)=0$ for all maximal ideals $m$ of $R$, prove that $M = 0$.

Comment: $M\otimes R$ is naturally isomorphic to $M$ via the isomorphism defined on pure tensors by $m\otimes r\mapsto rm.$ The inverse is given by $m\mapsto m\otimes 1$.

Comment: @DouglasMolin Yes but maybe my doubt wasn't very clear. I'm wondering what does $(M \otimes_R \varphi_m)(m)$ look like for $m \in M$.

Comment: $m\in M$ is identified with $m\otimes 1$ and should be mapped to whatever $m\otimes 1$ gets mapped to.

Comment: @DouglasMolin if that's the case, let me use $n \in M$ to avoid notation confusion. Then if my map makes sense, $n \otimes 1 = n$ gets mapped to $\frac{n}{1}\mathfrak{m} = 0$ by hypothesis and so $\frac{n}{1} \in \mathfrak{m}$. Thus $\frac{n}{1}$ is contained in the maximal ideal of $R_m$ which means that it is a nonunit. This also means that $n$ is a nonunit in $R$. Since $n$ was arbitrary, we must have that $n = 0$. This seems very forceful I'm not sure at all...

Comment: That doesn't make sense unfortunately. $n$ is an element of $M$, not $R$.

Comment: Anyway, this is connected with Nakayama's lemma. See Statement 4 on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakayama%27s_lemma